# JUnit test encounters NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, junit

I am trying to learn how to write a JUnit test.

here is all the content in Calculator.java.

```
public class Calculator {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

here is all the content in CalculatorTest.java.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {
    private static Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        int actual_rs = calculator.add(1, 2);
        assertEquals(3, actual_rs);
    }

}
```

[image]

how to fix this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadTestLoaderClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:309)
```

Comment: Since you are using Java 13, do you have Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) with the [Java 13 Support for Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-13-support-eclipse-2019-09-413) plug-in? Please show the whole stack trace, not just the first lines. Please show also the import statements, to be sure JUnit 4 and 5 wasn't mixed (are you sure you want to learn JUnit with an outdated version?).

Comment: Thank you. with that plug-in and JUnit5, everything is OK. plz mv it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **Java 13**, makes sure you have **Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)** with the **[Java 13 Support for Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-13-support-eclipse-2019-09-413)** plug-in (or Eclipse 2019-12 with built-in Java 13 support which will be released on 18 December 2019).

Make also sure, **not to mix JUnit 4 and 5**. For learning how to write a JUnit test, **JUnit 5 is recommended instead of** using the outdated previous version **JUnit 4**.